# trying to groupby and and expand the columns to reflect the grouped columns in every cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset of a groupby clause in the below format

| page | convert | # converted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| new | no | 3 |
|  | Yes | 4 |
| old | no | 5 |
|  | yes | 6 |

The first 2 rows are for. "page" = new . This data is grouped by "page".

I would like to have this displayed as

| page | convert | # converted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| new | no | 3 |
| new | Yes | 4 |
| old | no | 5 |
| old | yes | 6 |

Tried to use unstack function, but that creates a 2 way table, which is not what I want.

Any idea how to get this done ?

Comment: `df.reset_index()` after the groupby?

Comment: Thank you ! This works .